# Integer solutions of $p^2 + pm = m^3 $ where $p$ is a prime and $m$ positive

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I am trying to solve this question:

> Determine all pairs $(m,p)$ such that $m,p \in $ $\mathbb{Z^+}$ and $p$ a prime satisfying the equation $$p^2+pm=m^3$$

I did this but I am not sure how to follow:
$$
p^2+pm=m^3 \\
p(p+m) = m^3 \\
\implies p | m^3 \\
\implies p | m
\implies m=pn {\hspace{2mm}}(n \in \mathbb{Z^+}) \\
$$

From here, I have tried to substitute into the original equation:
$$
m=pn \\
(mn)^2 + (mn)m = m^3 \\
n^2+n=m \\
n(n+1)=m
$$
However, now I am not sure how to proceed. For reference, **the answer is (2,2)**

Comment: You substituted $mn$ instead of $pn$.

Comment: I don’t understand how do you get $(mn)^2 + (mn)m = m^3$?

Comment: Oh my god @mathcounterexamples.net! Thank you so much, this did it. I'll post an answer to this. Note to future self: double-check substitutions.

Comment: @miracle173 yup, I substituted wrongly, check my answer or mathcounterexamples.net's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mathcounterexamples.net pointed out, I was substituting $mn$ instead of $pn$. Once, I resolved this, the question is trivial:

Substituting into our equation and canceling a factor of $p^2$ we are left with $1 + n = pn^3$.

This implies that $n$ must divide $1$ and therefore $n = 1$ and
$m = 2$. The equation now simplifies to $p = 2$ and we conclude that the only solution is the pair $(2, 2)$.